# getting string bound cocoa

Tags: cocoa

I have an NSString object having string content as "Abc". It has font name, type and size as "Arial", "Bold" and "12.0" respectively.

How can i know the bounding rect of the the said string.

Answer (score 3):

NSString has a [boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSString_AppKitAdditions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:) method.